# Use mod_proxy to point to a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a Perch CMS install on a server subfolder (this is the main domain on a bulk hosting account, so there's no avoiding using a subfolder).

I WAS using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?MYSITE.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/SUBFOLDER/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /SUBFOLDER/$1

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ SUBFOLDER/index.php [L]
```

And i set the config paths in the CMS to include /SUBFOLDER/. Everything worked fine.

Then i found that the CMS uses DOCUMENT_ROOT in a lot of functions (and it's not as simple as finding them all and adding the subfolder), mainly for creation of pages. This means that new page files are stored in the server root, not the subfolder.

Perch support suggest using mod_proxy to point to the subdomain and remove all references in the PHP to the subfolder. I've read the documentation and don't see anything that seems relevant to this problem. Does anyone have an example usage similar to this, or know a good method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what the support is referring to is to proxy to the subdomain instead of rewriting to subfolder that is the subdomain. So make sure `/Subfolder` is setup correctly as a subdomain then you can do something like this to proxy to the subdomain using the `P` flag.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?MYSITE\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/SUBFOLDER/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subfolder.example.com/$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://subfolder.example.com/"

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ http://subfolder.example.com/index.php [P]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's put me in the right direction! As this is the top level domain on my bulk hosting i went with this:
`RewriteRule ^(example.com)?$ http://subfolder.example.com/$1 [P]` 
That works a charm for the home page but all scripts and links are broken. I can reach those through the subdomain path, but not the proxy one... Did i miss something?

Comment: Also, I'm in .htaccess so can't use ProxyPass.

Comment: you can remove the proxypassreverse line. why did you use this `RewriteRule ^(example.com)?$` that's not going to capture any of the pages.

Comment: Because i had tied myself in knots! This was the right answer... although it hasn't solved my problem all together. Thanks